# Error while starting my application in tomcat

Tags: spring

when i try to map applicationContext.xml file from web.xml for using spring ioc, my application was not starting showing following error in catalina.out

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
  /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>
```

> 04-Sep-2019 14:07:05.707 SEVERE
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userService' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'employeeService' while setting constructor argument; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'employeeService' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Could not
>   resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments
>   for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)      at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:326)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>         at
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1381)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:694)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)         at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)      at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>         at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeService' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching
>   constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple
>   parameters to avoid type ambiguities)         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>         at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
>         ... 55 more 04-Sep-2019 14:07:05.708 SEVERE
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file

Comment: Can you show please the full stacktrace and more logs if available?

Comment: Did you add ContextLoaderListener into web.xml ?

Comment: yes i added ContextListenerLoader in web.xml  @Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Context is the container initialized by a ContextLoaderListener or ContextLoaderServlet defined in the web.xml and the configuration would look something like this:

```
 <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml  </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and servlet tag for the servlet application contexts

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>app-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
</servlet>
```